# Windows server cannot read CI URL (PHP framework style URL)

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I have one application in Code Igniter with has URL style:
http://localhost:909/index.php/main/login/

PHP and MySQL has worked but I cannot access that URL's style in my IIS (Win server 2003).

I can successfully access http://localhost:909/info.php/ that contains phpinfo() script.

What should I check?

I wonder my IIS setting cannot read file as folder like CI has (index.php/main/login)
I need to change my IIS setting and leave the URL as it is.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Does the `Main` controller exist, and does it have a method called `login`? I would point you in the direction of the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry all, i just make a mistake on my code,
the index.php should be inside another subfolder inside localhost.

thanks for all your answer ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your route.php or you need to add a .htaccess file to configure the rewrite engine.
Maybe it can help you http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite